# iPhone App replace images

Tags: iphone, xcode, objective-c-2.0

I got a little problem. I use some images in my app. Today I wanted to replace them with new ones. But when I build and run the project I still get the old ones. I tried to touch the project and the new images but nothing seems to work. I deleted all references and files and imported the new images, but I still see just the old ones.
Does anyone know how to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Build -> Clean Targets (i think or something like this)

Comment: Does not seem to work... I tried to delete all images and clean all targets but the images are still in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your target and doing a fresh build. Xcode is probably not updating the files in the target properly (I've seen it do that a lot with the Copy Files build phase).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from the simulator or your iOS device and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have to get this question out of the way.... did you make sure that the cases match?

For the answer:
Simulator: clean all targets, clean, Reset the simulator and then try again
Device: clean all targets, clean, delete the app, reinstall